# Find exact match in a table in oracle using sql statements

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a situation where i need to insert a record only when the parameters passed in do not have exact match in table.
For e.g.,
i have a Role and a permission table:

```
Role:
-------
R1  
R2  
R3  


Permission:
-----------
P1  
P2  
P3
```

then there is a Role_Perm table:

```
Role|Permission:
----------------
R1 | P1   
R2 | P1  
R2 | P2 
R2 | P3  
R3 | P1
R3 | P3
```

Now the problem in hand is that i want to insert a new record in the Role_Perm table when the exact combination of permissions (given for a new role) is not already present in table;
for eg. 'R5 | P1, P2' should be inserted but 'R5 | P1, P3' should not be inserted.

I want to find if this combination already exists using a sql query before performing an insert operation. I need help with the query. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have permissions to change you table structure? Especially for Role_Perimission. You should use it as a bridge table for a many to many relation.

Comment: Role_perm table is not normalized. You need to make it as a look up table.

Comment: To be fair, a junction (many-to-many) table on its own won't solve the OP's actual problem.

Comment: First of all, this is poorly `normalized` database. You might want to read how to how to normalize your data structure properly, so you can access and manipulate your data properly. Is the ordering of `Permission` in role_perm given or can it be eg., `P2, P1` too ?

Comment: thanks for ol ur replies guys, i have altered it above to represent the actual structure, it is a normalized table in actual

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query at first:

```
with ins as (select column_value cv from table (sys.odcivarchar2list('P9', 'P1')))
select count(1) cnt 
  from (select listagg(cv, ',') within group (order by cv) list from ins) 
  join (select listagg(permission, ',') 
                       within group (order by permission) list 
          from role_perm group by role) using (list)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4c94/1)</sup>

... and if it returns 0 - perform insert. In first line put permissions which should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all These tables are not normalized,if you have the permission to change table structure, you have to consider following
01 Single column (in single row) should not have multiple values
02 So You have to create table with two columns Role, Permission with **composite Primary Key**  (use primary key for both columns)

Then you can't input both values in twice
eg:- we entered  R2 | P2 then you can enter R2 | P3  but You cant enter R2 | P2

simply Row cant be duplicate in this strucure

Comment: thank you for your quick response, i have put the third table to explain the requirement. In actual, we have multiple entries in the table corresponding to each 'row : permission' combination (the way you rightly mentioned), and yes no duplicates are allowed

Comment: you are welcome . Then it is better Create the table what I mentioned. write a select query to view data as your requirment

Comment: the table is as you mentioned. I need help with the query as i want a match with exact given params(permissions), and since the given params are dynamic, we cannot create a sql with '='. I have also tried with 'IN' operator, but again it returns all rows where it matches

Comment: what is the database you are using ?